# Get class methods with annotation with org.refelections

Tags: java, reflection

I have used org.reflections (http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) in my project for loading classes with certain annotations. Now I have class and I need to get all methods with annotation that I have made myself. But when I create Reflections object, it asks just for package name, so if I would use getMethodsAnnotatedWith method, it would get all methods from given package classes, but I want to get methods from my class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
    final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.your.SampleClass");
    final Method[] declaredMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (final Method method : declaredMethods)
    {
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(YourAnnotationClass .class))
        {
            //Do what you want
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's rather simple if you have a `Class` object. See [this reference](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

Important code part is:

```
Class c = Class.forName(args[0]);
Method m[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
```

That way you will get an array of `Method` objects to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Reflections documentation, in order query for methods annotations you should instantiate Reflections like this:

`new Reflections("my.package", new MethodAnnotationsScanner())`

Another option is to use the Reflections query api, such that,

`Set<Method> set = getAllMethods(reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(...), withAnnotation(methodAnnotation))`

`import static org.Reflections.*;`